# ocamlopt: Error during linking

Tags: c, ocaml

Well, I made this toy:

sql_conn.c:

```c
// https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html
// http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

CAMLprim value connect(value dbname, value dbuser, value dbpassword){
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(con,"localhost",String_val(dbuser), String_val(dbpassword),String_val(dbname),0,NULL,0);
    return (value) con;
}

CAMLprim value print_query(value con, value tbl, value field, value constraint){
    char query[100];
    sprintf(query, "select * from %s where %s='%s';",(char *) tbl,(char *) field,(char *) constraint);
    mysql_query((MYSQL*) con, query);

    MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result((MYSQL*) con);
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
    { 
        for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
        { 
            printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
        } 
            printf("\n"); 
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
    return Val_unit;
}
```

main.ml:

```ml
type dbconn

external print_query: dbconn -> string -> string -> string -> unit = "print_query"

external connect: string -> string -> string -> dbconn = "connect"

let database = "dogs";;
let user = "root";;
let pwd = "kafka";;

let tbl = "dogs";;
let field = "Name";;
let arg = "reximus";;
let db = connect database user pwd;;
print_query db tbl field arg;;
```

Makefile

```
main:
    g++ -c sql_conn.c -lmysqlclient
    ocamlopt main.ml
    ./a.out
```

And connect(...) works, but I get the error:

```
g++ -c sql_conn.c -lmysqlclient
ocamlopt main.ml
main.o: In function `camlMain__entry':
main.ml:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `print_query'
main.o: In function `camlMain__6':
main.ml:(.data+0xa8): undefined reference to `print_query'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

On make. Any pointers appreciated. It says the problem is with linking, but when the only method was connect(...) it worked fine. I'm not a seasoned C programmer (if you couldn't tell), so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Also, should a post like this also be tagged with mysql?

Comment: Why are you using `g++` to compile a C file? And why are you specifying linker options (`-lmysqlclient`) when you're disabling linking (`-c`)?

Comment: That's just what I saw on the internet. removing the -c flag doesn't help. The linker option is required for mysql access, for whatever reason.

Comment: No, the `-c` flag is necessary and the linker option is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you're not getting an error for `connect` because there's already a [`connect` function in the standard library](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html). I strongly suggest renaming your function because `mysql_real_connect` likely uses the standard `connect` internally and this would cause infinite recursion if you override it like this.

---

Quoting from [the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/intfc.html#sec416):

> If you are using the native-code compiler `ocamlopt`, the `-custom` flag is not needed, as the final linking phase of `ocamlopt` always builds a standalone executable. To build a mixed OCaml/C executable, execute the `ocamlopt` command with:
>
> - the names of the desired OCaml native object files (`.cmx` and `.cmxa` files);
> - the names of the C object files and libraries (`.o`, `.a`, `.so` or `.dll` files) that implement the required primitives.

[And also](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/native.html#sec303):

> The `ocamlopt` command has a command-line interface very close to that of `ocamlc`. It accepts the same types of arguments, and processes them sequentially, after all options have been processed:
>
> [...]
>
> - Arguments ending in `.cmx` are taken to be compiled object code. These files are linked together, along with the object files obtained by compiling `.ml` arguments (if any), and the OCaml standard library, to produce a native-code executable program. [...]
> - Arguments ending in `.c` are passed to the C compiler, which generates a `.o`/`.obj` object file. This object file is linked with the program.

And later:

> **`-cclib -llibname`**
> Pass the `-llibname` option to the linker . This causes the given C library to be linked with the program.

---

**DISCLAIMER:** I haven't actually tested the following steps. This is just what I think would make sense from reading the documentation.

---

From this I assume a correct compilation command would look like

```
ocamlopt sql_conn.c main.ml -cclib -lmysqlclient
```

Or in a Makefile:

```
a.out: sql_conn.c main.ml
        ocamlopt sql_conn.c main.ml -cclib -lmysqlclient
```

(If you want to add a `main` target that also executes the file, I'd do something like

```
.PHONY: main
main: a.out
        ./a.out
```

)

If you want to separate the steps, it would look like this:

1. Compile `sql_conn.c` into `sql_conn.o`:

   ```
    gcc -c sql_conn.c
   ```
2. Compile `main.ml` into `main.cmx` (among other things):

   ```
    ocamlopt -c main.ml
   ```
3. Link them together into an executable:

   ```
    ocamlopt sql_conn.o main.cmx -cclib -lmysqlclient
   ```

Or in Makefile form:

```
sql_conn.o: sql_conn.c
        gcc -c sql_conn.c

main.cmx: main.ml
        ocamlopt -c main.ml

a.out: sql_conn.o main.cmx
        ocamlopt sql_conn.o main.cmx -cclib -lmysqlclient
```

---

Problems with your commands:

> ```
> g++ -c sql_conn.c -lmysqlclient
> ```

`g++` selects the C++ compiler and prepares to link with the C++ standard libraries. `-lmysqlclient` adds the `mysqlclient` library to the set.

But `-c` tells it not to perform the linking step (so the C++ standard library and `mysqlclient` are ignored), and the filename (ending with `.c`) makes it switch to the C compiler.

The whole thing is equivalent to

```
gcc -c sql_conn.c
```

This produces `sql_conn.o` (an object file containing compiled C code).

> ```
> ocamlopt main.ml
> ```

This tells `ocamlopt` to compile `main.ml`, link it with the standard OCaml libraries, and produce an executable called `a.out`. There's nothing that tells it to look in `sql_conn.o`, so that file is simply ignored.

It's here that you're getting a linker error because `print_query` wasn't found (it was defined in `sql_conn.o`). As mentioned above, you're not getting an error for `connect` because a symbol of that name (albeit with an incompatible signature, but the linker doesn't know that) already exists in the system library.

Comment: This threw a 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)', I tried doing "ocamlopt main.ml -cc "gcc sql_conn.c -lmysqlclient" and got the same error.

Comment: @ZacharyBechhoefer Did you rename `connect` in both files?

Comment: I did! It could be unrelated, somethinga bout my print or sprintf.

Comment: @ZacharyBechhoefer For one, you're missing the `CAMLparam` / `CAMLreturn` stuff from https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/intfc.html#sec439.

Comment: @ZacharyBechhoefer I'm also pretty sure you can't just cast a random `MYSQL` handle to `value`. See e.g. how [this example](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.06/intfc.html#sec447) wraps `WINDOW`.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm supposed to use CAMLlocal1, caml_alloc and Store_field. Something like that, I'll try it, thanks!